# iOS Access dynamically created label from other method

Tags: ios, dynamic

I have created a TableView that contains UIViews, which hold a few other elements.  These UIViews are created dynamically, as the data is called from a server. Inside each UIView there is a UILabel and a UIButtton.  Once the button is clicked, I would like to have the corresponding label updated with some value. I was able to modify the UIButton and the view itself but unable to modify the UILabel. Here is an example of the method that is called when a UIButton is called. Right now it will change the background color of the corresponding UIView, but the label element does not work as intended. How can accomplish modifying this label element which is a subelement of the UIView?

```
- (void) heartPlus:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;

    NSInteger id_num = button.tag;

    UIView * view = (UIView *)[self.view.superview viewWithTag:id_num];
    UILabel * label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:id_num];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

}
```

Creating the UIView along with adding the corresponding elements.

```
UIView * msgView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,offSet,320,120)] init];
[msgView setTag:someID];

// Add button
UIButton * buttonUpdate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
buttonUpdate.tag = someID;
[buttonUpdate addTarget:self action:@selector(heartPlus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UILabel * labelHeart = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280,100,20,10)] init];
labelHeart.tag = someID;

// Add each element to the msgView
[msgView addSubview:buttonUpdate];
[msgView addSubview:labelHeart];
```

Comment: sender is a UIButton in a custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: Yes, I have added the code that is used to create each UIButton above.

Comment: Did you check if label is not nil? Post more code, how label is created and added to the view. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: I've added additional code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still some missing code, but as far as I can see you have the error in `heartPlus` method and `viewWithTag` does not return the correct view. Therefore the assignment of `backgroundColor` fails. The explanation is below:

You are first getting the parent view of view that contains `UIButton` and `UILabel`. I assume your view hierarchy looks something like this:

- UITableViewCell

  - UIView (tag: someID)

    - UILabel (tag: someID)
    - UIButton (tag: someID)

So, if I assume there is no error in the line below and that it returns correct `UITableViewCell` (or whatever other view is the parent of both `UILabel` and `UIButton`):

```
UIView * view = (UIView *)[self.view.superview viewWithTag:id_num];
```

**We can clearly see the problem with both `UILabel` and `UIButton` having the same tags. So if you ask the UITableViewCell for the view with tag, it will simply fail - returns nil.**

There are multiple solutions to this problem, but the problem remains the same.

**Do not give the `UILabel` the same tag as `UIButton`.**

I assume you are a beginner with Objective-C so I would suggest you first look into some tutorials of how UIViews work. But to make it easier for you, here are few options:

- **Create a custom subclass of the `UIView` with `UIView` properties.**
- Use unique tags for `UILabel` and for `UIButton`. To find the correct `id_num` on click, use introspection and `sender`'s `superview`, which is passed to you in a method.
- You could easily loop through `UIView`'s subviews property (which is an array) and find the UILabel manually - this works, if there is only one `UILabel` or you are looking for all of them.

But in either case, you need to rethink of how `UITableView` works. It is not a good practice to ask `self.view.superview` for `viewWithTag` and your method could already fail at this point.

Comment: I was able to implement what I was looking for by looping through the subviews as you suggested. However, this method will not work very well as the number of objects within each UIView grows. Do you have any suggested resources for creating a subclass UIView with UIView properties as you suggested?

Comment: Exactly, the method mentioned works only when there is a single UILabel, otherwise you are just juggling pointers and you cannot know which is which for sure. First read some resources about properties: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html And then read about UIView's: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html Apple Documentation is a great resource! And if you are serious about programming, learn how to find resources yourself asap.